# Как задать в регулярном выражении любой порядок из данных элементов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть допустим 3 числа 10,20,35

Нужно сделать регулярное выражение так, чтобы подходило любое сочетание именно этих цифр, т.е.:

```
10,20,35;
35,10,20;
20,35,10;
```

и.т.п.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть это регулярное выражение?

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите работать именно со строкой текста в вашей задаче?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наиболее корректным в данной ситуации будет использовать backreference для удаления из совпадения уже совпавших альтернатив

```
(10|35|20),(?!\1)(10|35|20),(?!\1|\2)(10|35|20)
```

или более красивая форма записи:

```
(10|35|20),(?!\1)((?1)),(?!\1|\2)((?1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(10|20|35)([\\,])(10|20|35)([\\,])(10|20|35)$
```

Comment: Можно и короче сделать ^(10|20|35|,){5};$, но и так и так будет находить и варианты вроде 10,10,10

Comment: Ваш вариант даже 5 запятых найдет, @Veliant :) в отличии от кода выше.