# Поиск всех слов в любом порядке

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражением.

Есть тексты:

```
Вчера вечером мама мыла раму в квартире.
Вчера вечером мыла раму мама в квартире.
Вчера вечером раму мыла мама в квартире.
```

Нужно найти в текстах куски со словами: мама, мыла, раму. Ключевой момент - мы не знаем в какой именно последовательности будут стоять слова в тексте.

Нужна какая-то регулярка, которая будет выцеплять из примеров все варианты:
мама мыла раму
мыла раму мама
раму мыла мама,
причем из исходных данных у нас только 3 слова - мама, мыла, раму и знание, что эти слова в тексте должны быть разделены пробелами.

Comment: Видимо вам на фриланс биржу с такой постановкой вопроса.

Comment: А что не так? Непонятно объяснил?

Comment: Нужна регулярка, которая будет искать в тексте все подаваемые на вход слова в любой последовательности.

Пример:

Текст: Вчера вечером мама мыла раму в квартире.
На вход подаем слова мыла, раму, мама.
Должен находиться кусок текста "мама мыла раму".

Comment: 99% что в общем случае такое не решается только регулярными выражениями. Отсюда вопрос: на каком языке вам нужно решение?

Comment: Ну и из вопроса непонятно, что вы пытались сделать сами и что именно не получилось)

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev, закодил решение на php методом перебора всех вариантов: долго, т.к. у меня есть и 10 словные фразы, а сколько там вариантов может быть сами понимаете. подумал может все намного проще и есть регулярка для этого.

Comment: @yevgeniyche если у Вас уже есть решение и Вам не нужна помощь, Вы можете опубликовать свой ответ и отметить его решением либо удалить вопрос за ненадобностью.

Comment: так я же написал, что решение тупого перебора не катит. для 10-словной фразы сутки уйдут на перебор.

Comment: @yevgeniyche, то есть вам будет достаточно любого, приемлемого по скорости работы алгоритма? Или вы хотите, что бы пользователи ru.SO написали весь код за вас?

Comment: если алгоритм будет действительно приемлемым по скорости, например, чтобы матчились все совпадения для 20-словной фразы (с любым порядком слов в тексте) хотя бы за 10 секунд.

Comment: @Alex, в одном из комментариев выше ТС указал, что язык программирования -- php

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да, спасибо, уже увидели. но все равно пусть код покажет, нужно же видеть что он уже сделал.

Comment: вопрос: *Мама вчера вечером мыла в квартире Раму*, на входе те же "мама", "мыла, "раму" - что должно быть на выходе? Вся строка? А если строка будет вида *Мама вчера вечером в квартире мыла* - что здесь на выходе должно быть?

Comment: Тут ничего, т.к. три нужных слова не идут подряд.

Comment: _"Нужна какая-то регулярка"_ -- нужна именно одна регулярка? или все равно как решить задачу? и надо для "мама", "мыла, "раму" или могут быть другие варианты?

Comment: Stack другие конечно могут быть, у меня на практике фразы и из 30 слов могут быть. Можно и алгоритм, мне нужно найти все вхождения фразы в тексте, при чем не важно в какой последовательности слова из этой фразы будут стоять в тексте. Все слова из фразы должны разделяться только пробелами.

Comment: Просто оставю: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349815/

Comment: @yevgeniyche _" у меня на практике фразы и из 30 слов могут быть. "_ -- если между ними стоят запятые, и т.д., то см. [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486403/196972)

Comment: @ReinRaus: отметили бы дубликатом )

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ну тут уже столько ответов дали, когда я зашел. И к тому же в том вопросе разделитель запятая, а в этом- пробел. Иногда это очень критично для регулярных выражений :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 слова, всего 6 вариантов расположения их подряд через пробел : )

```
/(мама\ мыла\ раму|мама\ раму\ мыла|мыла\ мама\ раму|мыла\ раму\ мама|раму\ мама\ мыла|раму\ мыла\ мама)/
```

---

**Серьёзней и чуть покороче:**

```
/(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(мама|мыла|раму)/
```

- одно из трёх слов
- пробел
- НЕ первый матч, но одно из трёх слов
- пробел
- НИ первый НИ второй матч, но одно из трёх слов.

**Тесты:**

```js
var tests = {
   "мама мыла раму": true
  ,"мама раму мыла": true
  ,"мыла мама раму": true
  ,"мыла раму мама": true
  ,"раму мама мыла": true
  ,"раму мыла мама": true
  ,"мама мыла мама": false
  ,"раму раму мама": false
  ,"мама,мыла?раму": false
 }
 ,i
 ,regexp = /(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(мама|мыла|раму)/
 ,passed = true
;

for( s in tests) {
  if( !!s.match(regexp) !== tests[s]) {
    passed = false;
    break;
  }
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = passed ? 'passed' : 'failed';
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Похоже это то, что надо (я про второй вариант, который серьезней и короче), спасибо!

Comment: Только есть один момент. Тут будет матчится и такое: https://regex101.com/r/zE6vS5/3 (см. первую строку и вторую). Нужно чтобы проверялся признак начала и конца слова. Никак не получается \b воткнуть сюда.

Comment: @yevgeniyche, как бы `(?:^|\b)(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(мама|мыла|раму)(?:$|\b)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, достаточно было: \b(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(мама|мыла|раму)\b но у меня толи сглючило, толи я ступил не сработало с первого раза. Вроде бы нашел решение задачи, респект.

Comment: `/(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?(1))\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(?(1))/` еще чуть-чуть короче :)

Comment: @ReinRaus не работает в JS: "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group". Искал вариант один раз указать группу и ссылаться на неё, но не нашёл пока рабочий в JS. [Именованные группы](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) тоже не работают. В php не проверял.

Comment: Если js, то там нет рекурсии, значит сокращение такое не получится. Я исходил из принципа, что регулярные выражения без метки, по-умолчанию так сказать, это наверно PCRE.

Comment: @ReinRaus как раз понадобилось сокращать размер выражения, в 30-словных фразах оно может быть очень длинным. Но с предложенным вариантом `/(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)(?(1))\ (?!\1)(?!\2)(?(1))/` проблемы: https://regex101.com/r/zS5rY9/1

Comment: @ReinRaus разобрался, нужно так: `/(мама|мыла|раму)\ (?!\1)((?1))\ (?!\1)(?!\2)((?1))/`

Comment: Исправил https://regex101.com/r/zS5rY9/2

Answer (score 6):

Пытаться решать задачу "в лоб" при помощи регулярных выражений, на мой взгляд, не правильно. Опишу алгоритм того, как можно решить задачу в общем виде, не останавливаясь на деталях реализации для того или иного языка программирования.

Итак, я бы решал задачу вот так:

1. Обозначим исходное множество слов, которые нужно найти как `T`. Пусть так же `T1` - это множество *еще не найденных* слов. Очевидно, что `T1` является подмножеством `T`. В начале работы алгоритма `T1 = T`.
2. Разбейте исходную строку на массив слов (массив `W`). Это можно сделать, например, выделив подстроки, разделенные пробелом.
3. Отчистите каждое слово массива `W` от обрамляющих знаков препинания (можно сделать частью п.2).
4. Выберите первое слово массива `W` как "текущее"
5. Проверьте входит ли текущее слово в множество `T1`.
6. Если текущее слово встречается в множестве `T1`, значит вы нашли точку потенциального вхождения требуемых слов. Сократите множество `T1`, исключив найденное слово. Если в множестве `T1` больше не осталось слов, то исходная строка содержит все слова из набора. Работу алгоритма можно завершать.
7. Если текущее слово не встречается в множестве `T1`, верните его состояние в первоначальное (`T1 = T`)
8. Перейдите к следующему слову из массива `W` и повторите действия пп. 5-7

Код писать не буду принципиально, можете минусовать =)

**UPD:**

Для расширения алгоритма на поиск всех вхождений фразы в тексте, достаточно в п. 6 вместо завершения алгоритма, приводить множество `T1` в исходное состоянии (`T1 = T`) и переходить к следующему слову в массиве `W`.

Comment: не вижу причин минусовать, в вопросе тоже кодом не пахнет, а алгоритм в общем виде правильный )

Comment: @rdorn, это заметка, скорее, для ТС, чем для сообщества в целом))

Comment: Этот алго не очень подходит для задачи, т.к. мне нужно сматчить все вхождения группы слов в произвольном порядке, а не просто проверить есть ли они в тексте. Если быть точнее - мне нужно посчитать количество вхождений фразы в текст, при чем с любым порядком слов в этой фразе.

Comment: Этот алгоритм как раз и занимается поиском фразы (идущие подряд слова) в тексте. При этом слова могут идти в произвольном порядке. Расширить алгоритм для поиска всех вхождений фразы -- тривиальная задача.

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен. Регулярные выражения надо сперва изучить, прежде чем пытаться применять их в реальном коде.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать примерно такое выражение

```
/((?: +(?:мама|мыла|раму)){3})(?= |$)/
```

Которое вернет вам подстроки содержащие подряд 3 слова из списка, но оно отлично среагирует и на "мама мама мама". Поэтому вам надо на вашем языке программирования, после получения этой подстроки, убедится, что в строке присутствуют действительно все три разных слова.

Пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iE7zH5/2)

Comment: Первоначальное выделение строк не сработает для `мама, мыла; раму` (пунктуация)

Comment: TC про пунктуацию ни слова не сказал и привел строки без нее. Поэтому в ответе стоит "_примерно_ такое выражение", а не "вот _такое_ выражение". Кроме того у вопросе явно сказано "знание, что эти слова в тексте _должны быть разделены пробелами_."

Comment: @Mike а запятые и т.д. как-то можно учитывать в выражении? у ТС сказано "у меня на практике фразы и из 30 слов могут быть".

Answer (score 1):

Пример на C#

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Match[] search(string line, string[] words) {
    return words.Select(w => Regex.Match(line, "\\s+(" + w + ")[\\s\\.,]+"))
        .OrderBy(m => m.Index)
        .ToArray();
}
bool IsSeq(Match[] ms) {
    for (var i = 1; i < ms.Length; i++) {
        var a = ms[i - 1];
        var b = ms[i];
        if (a.Index + a.Length + 1 < b.Index) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Тест

```cs
var lines = new[] {
    "Вчера вечером мама помыла раму в квартире.",
    "Вчера вечером раму, мама..... мыла в квартире.",
    "Вчера вечером мыла раму мама в квартире.",
    "Вчера мама вечером раму мыла в квартире.",
    "Вчера вечером раму в квартире.",
    "Вчера вечером мыла в квартире."};
var words = new[] { "мама", "мыла", "раму" };
foreach (var line in lines) {
    var s = search(line, words);
    Console.WriteLine(IsSeq(s) + "\t\t" + line);
}
```

Результат

```
False  Вчера вечером мама помыла раму в квартире.
True   Вчера вечером раму, мама..... мыла в квартире.
True   Вчера вечером мыла раму мама в квартире.
False  Вчера мама вечером раму мыла в квартире.
False  Вчера вечером раму в квартире.
False  Вчера вечером мыла в квартире.
```

Comment: Ваш пример не верно работает для строки `Вечером мама опять мыла раму.`. ТС хочет, чтобы слова в фразе шли подряд: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486345/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5#comment566565_486345

Comment: Плюс к этому, если даже смотреть на позиции в массиве, фраза "Вчера вечером обмыла раму мама в квартире." даст абсолютно нормальные смещения ...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"ТС хочет, чтобы слова в фразе шли подряд:"_ -- ок. не обратил внимание. исправлю.

Comment: @Mike _"фраза "Вчера вечером обмыла раму мама в квартире." даст абсолютно нормальные смещения"_ -- переписал на c# и добавил проверку пробелов перед словом и после.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо товарищу **Sergiks**, получилось вот так:

**для примера из шапки:**
\b(мама|мыла|раму) (?!\1)((?1)) (?!\1)(?!\2)((?1))\b

**если еще и словоформы надо учитывать:**
\b((?:мама|мамы)|(?:мыла|мыли)|(?:раму|рамы)) (?!\1)((?1)) (?!\1)(?!\2)((?1))\b

- это идеальные варианты, для моей задачи 20-словные фразы, да еще и с учетем словоформ в текстах ищет мгновенно, намного лучше моего старого варианта с перебором возможных вариантов и сверкой каждого при помощи preg_match_all

Comment: Чтобы сказать «спасибо» просто отметьте нужный ответ зеленой галочкой.